# Set context root for spring annotation based web app

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

How can set the context root for a annotation based spring web app? Sample application found in following link,
https://github.com/bkielczewski/example-spring-mvc-initializer

In browser I can access it as,
`http://localhost:8080/`

I want to change it as,
`http://localhost:8080/spring`

Thanks,
Charith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your pom.xml to include web-app configuration. See below

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.6.v20130930</version>
    <configuration>
          <webApp>
              <contextPath>/spring</contextPath>
          </webApp>
          <httpConnector>
               <port>8080</port>
               <host>localhost</host>
          </httpConnector>
          <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```